# Bayesian structural equation modelling - do all parameters have to show good diagnostics (e.g., autocorrelation, trace plot etc.)?

Tags: bayesian, autocorrelation, markov-chain-montecarlo, structural-equation-modeling, traceplots

Would a Bayesian SEM model  only be accepted by a scientific journal if all parameters show good diagnostics ? (e.g., autocorrelation, trace plot etc.).

Is it realistic to build such a model? Or is it ok to say that some parameters are more trustworthy than others?

Comment: always risky to have "just a few" untrustworthy params when they may interact in funny ways. Of course, best to have a good model that works perfectly, but when this isn't possible, it's essential to understand what's going wrong (even if we can't fix it). Autocorrelation isn't a problem (it just means you run your sampler for longer), but in SEM it's super easy to make you're variables unidentifiable, so identifiability checks are where I would start.